# generating a sequence of numbers

Tags: java, sequences

I was trying to generate a sequence of numbers.
Let it be (i j k),

```
1 1 1, 1 1 4, 1 2 3, 1 3 2
2 1 1, 2 1 4, 2 2 3, 2 3 2,
3 1 1, 3 1 4, and so on..
```

The only condition is that, there is maximum for i, j & k.

So far I have come up with a method as shown below, but this does not work for all cases.

Output:

```
1 1 1, 1 1 4, 1 2 3, 1 2 2, 
1 2 1, 1 1 4, 1 2 3 ...
```

Code:

```
seqGen(3, 2, 4, 3);

private static void seqGen(int line_max, int i_max, int k_max, int j_max) {

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;

    while (i <= i_max) {

        System.out.println((i + 1) + " " + (j + 1) + " " + (k + 1));
        int k_ = (k + line_max) % k_max;
        int j_ = ((k + line_max) / k_max) % j_max;
        i = ((k + line_max) / k_max) / j_max;

        k = k_;
        j = j_;

    }
}
```

Any idea what I'm missing??

Comment: We could try and infer the rules for generating the sequence, but I think it would better if you question stated them explicitly.

Comment: You need to be more descriptive about what your variable names mean? Obviously i_max, j_max and k_max are the max values that i,j,k can take on, but what is line_max? You invoke seqGen(3, 2, 4, 3);, and expected outputs like 1,1,4; which exceeds your line_max.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for but I took a stab at solving your problem.

First off, you should get into the habit of explaining your problem in a clear and concise manor to help people understand what your problem is. Second, you should get used to using widely used camel case variable naming i.e. i_max -> iMax. Lastly, you really shouldn't come here and just post a code snippet and ask "Any idea what i'm missing??" This is frowned upon in the community; You really should come here and show what you've tried, what is the outcome you're trying to achieve and why you think that isn't happening...

With that being said here is a solution that solves the problem I think you're asking.

```
HashMap<List<Integer>, Boolean> sequences  =  new HashMap<List<Integer>, Boolean>(); 
int lineMax;
int iMax;
int kMax;
int jMax;

private void setMaxes(int _lineMax, int _iMax, int _kMax, int _jMax) {
    if (_iMax + _kMax + _jMax > _lineMax){
        //throw an error right?
    }
    lineMax = _lineMax;
    iMax = _iMax;
    kMax = _kMax;
    jMax = _jMax;
}


private void seqGen(int currentI, int currentJ, int currentK) {
    if (!sequences.containsKey(Arrays.asList(currentI, currentJ, currentK))) {
        if (currentI <= iMax && currentJ <= jMax && currentK <= kMax 
                && currentI+currentJ+currentK <= lineMax) {
            sequences.put(Arrays.asList(currentI, currentJ, currentK), true);
            System.out.println(Arrays.asList(currentI, currentJ, currentK));
            seqGen(currentI+1, currentJ, currentK);
            seqGen(currentI, currentJ+1, currentK);
            seqGen(currentI, currentJ, currentK+1);
        }
    }
}
```

[Run an example here](http://ideone.com/18kK6x)

Comment: The question is ridiculously underspecified even though the OP has posted it repeatedly. Doesn't posting code encourage asking really bad questions that can't help anyone? You didn't say what problem you think the OP wants to solve either, so does your code help anyone else?